# How to dir all directories and subdirectories having a particular pattern match?

Tags: windows, cmd

Windows command line to return all the directories and sub-directories matching a particular pattern.

```
dir "e:\*.*" /A:-D /B /S
```

Will return all subdirectories under e:.
However, I want all subdirectories under e:\ which names include or are named ".backup"

Comment: Are you really working with MS-DOS, the OS from the 1980s,  or do you rather mean the Windows Command Prompt? Anyway: `dir /S /B /A:D "E:\*.backup"` (note that `/A:-D` returns *files* but not directories as you claimed)...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: dir /S /B /A:D "E:\*.backup*"
Win10 build 1903
Thanks